# Can't access v4beta1 APis of Google cloud talent solution

Tags: node.js, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-talent-solution, google-api-services-jobs

I am trying to use the new version v4beta1 of Google Cloud talent solution, but I am getting the permission error, have tried with all the required permissions using the JSON file, using the API key, but to no success.

Constantly getting this error -

> PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission

Answer (score 0):

You should change the API access permission to **Owner**

Comment: For example `sudo chown myUser`

Answer (score 0):

You should export the path to JSON file with the key as [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS](https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/before-you-begin#set_your_authentication_environment_variable) env variable:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
```